# Reverse array function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

so I have made a program that works in the following way.

user decides how big the array is.

user then fills the array with x chosen integers, e.g. if they choose to make an array 5 large, they are then asked to fill the array with 5 numbers. However I'm a little stuck on how I can do this, once this bit is done everything else should work I believe as I have tested it by hard coding it with assigned values and the function dose reverse the program.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

void reverse(int [], int);
void printarray(int [], int );

void printarray(int arr[], int count)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                cout<<arr[i]<<' ';

        cout<<'\n';
}

void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
     int temp;
     for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
     {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[count-i-1];
            arr[count-i-1] = temp;
     }
}

int main ()
{
        int x;
        cout << "how big is this thing " << endl;
        cin >> 
        const int SIZE = x;
        int arr [SIZE] = {., ., ., ., ., ., ., . , ., .};

        cout<<"Before reverse\n";
        printarray(arr, SIZE);
        reverse(arr, SIZE);
        cout<<"After reverse\n";
        printarray(arr, SIZE);

        return 0;
}
```

I do believe that I have to use a for loop or something to repeat and enter the integers into each index of the array, sorry it's been so long since I have done arrays.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SIZE` must be known at compile-time for an array. If the user can change the size of the array, you either have to used a fixed maximum size, or use a different container such as `vector` instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework exercise? In most cases you would be using something like std::vector but I guess for this you will need to be sticking to native arrays.

```
int arr[SIZE];
```

This will create an array on the stack, and the size must be known at compile time. If you don't know the size until runtime you will need allocate the array on the heap using the `new` keyword (or via something like `malloc`)

```
int *arr = new int[x];
```

You'll need to free this memory yourself once you're done though

```
delete[] arr;
```

That should be enough to get you started and point you int right direction. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Cause the size of array is unknown at compile time you can not use `int array[SIZE]` construct.

You need to allocate the memory at run-time with `new`:

```
int x;
cout << "how big is this thing " << endl;
cin >> x;
int *arr = new int[x];

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  cout << "enter arry[" << i << "]" << endl;
  cin >> arr[i];
}

cout<<"Before reverse\n";
printarray(arr, SIZE);
reverse(arr, SIZE);
cout<<"After reverse\n";
printarray(arr, SIZE);

delete[] arr;
```

The `delete[] arr` operator frees the allocated array. You should free every allocated memory blocks to avoid memory-leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverse(int arr[], int count)
{
     int temp;
     for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
     {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[count-i-1];
            arr[count-i-1] = temp;
     }
}

void print_array(int my_array[], int array_size)
{
    std::cout << "Your array: ";
    for (int x = 0; x <array_size; x++) {
        std::cout << my_array[x] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int array_size;
    std::cout << "how big is this thing " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> array_size;

    int my_array[array_size];

    std::cout << "Please enter the elements of the array. Press ENTER after each element." << std::endl;
    for (int x = 0; x <array_size; x++) {
        std::cin >> my_array[x];
    }

    print_array(my_array, array_size);

    std::cout << "Reverse array..." << std::endl;
    reverse(my_array, array_size);
    print_array(my_array, array_size);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned from M.M, use std::vector and insert to the beginning of the vector (you don't need you're reverse)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    int n_values;

    std::cout << "How mutch numbers ?";
    std::cin >> n_values;

    std::cout << "Now Enter " << n_values << " Values : ";
    for(auto i=0; i<n_values; i++)
    {
        int tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;

        values.insert(values.begin(), tmp); 
    }

    for(auto elem : values)
        std::cout << elem << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just, regarding good programming habits, if the input were coming from a file, and could be more than say 5 or 7, then this approach has quadratic time, O(n²). If instead you'd used `.push_back` and a final call to `std::reverse` (free function) you'd have more reasonable O(n).

Comment: Why use `std::begin`? I thought it was something you'd use in templates only, but here you know it's a vector already why not `.begin()`? I'm just curious

Comment: @szx it's a good habit to always use `begin(x)`  ; then you don't have to change syntax when changing between a vector and an array for example.